# Действия над элементами списка через кнопки

Tags: android, java

Доброе время суток.

В списке выделяю объект, список отображает содержимое БД.
Нужно удалить или изменить данные в БД. Все эти действия нужно делать через кнопки (ImageButton).

Проблема в том, что я не пойму, как делается. 
То ли при выборе элемента в списке через setOnItemClickListener сохранять в глобальную переменнуе данные, по которым потом что-то делать в БД, то ли как-то все можно сделать через события своего адаптера, то как их потом выполнить и вызвать.

Comment: У вас каждый элемент в списке - это данные из БД + кнопки управления? Или по клику на элемент списка вы его выделяете, а уже потом жмёте на кнопку управления (которая в одном экземпляре где-то в меню/action bar)?

Comment: Да верно. Одна кнопка в bar и каждый элемент это данные из БД. В ListView два текстовых поля

Comment: > при выборе элемента в списке через
> setOnItemClickListener сохранять в
> глобальную переменные данные по
> которым потом чет делать в БД    

Именно так. Можно при клике по элементу так же показывать меню, например, в котором один из пунктов - "удалить"

Comment: я пробывал делать через удержание setOnItemLongClickListener  но толи не правильно там  интерфейс сделал толи мне просто так не понравилось.  почемуто мне через кнопки удобней.   ОК всм спс я понял направление